Laravel Scout gets just all records of the table ignoring any params
It seems that I did all the instructions from Laravel documentation to use Scout with 'database' engine.
Environment settings:
SCOUT_DRIVER=database
Migration:
    public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->index()->nullable();
        $table->string('status')->default(StatusEnum::TODO);
        $table->string('priority')->default(\App\Enums\PriorityEnum::MID)->index();
        $table->string('title')->fullText();
        $table->text('description')->fullText();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->timestamp('completed_at')->nullable();
    });
}

with the fullText indexes.
Have done sail artisan scout:import "App\Models\Task" command.
Code for retrieving
Task::search($value)->get(); where $value is coming from request.
This query returns all records from the 'tasks' table, which I don't need of course.
What didn't I do?
HELP me Please

Ensure your Task model uses the Searchable trait
class Task extends Model
{
use Searchable;
}

@RahulThakur
My Task model code uses Searchable trait class.
Maybe I need some undocumented features/classes?
